# JqueryUI tooltip positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am using JqueryUI.tooltip to make a picture visible when hovering over a text.
http://jsfiddle.net/gwj230rn/

```
    <script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $(".imagehover").tooltip
        ({    
            items: "[data-src]",
            content: function () 
            {
                return '<img src="' + $(this).data("src") + '" />';
            },
            tooltipClass:"tooltipImg",
            position:
            { 
                within: ".usertable"

            },
            track:true  
        });
    });
</script>
```

the .usertable is a table which is always larger than the browsers visible area. Is there another parameter like "visiblearea" or something like that for within positioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div.ui-tooltip {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

This solution readjusts the tooltip div to wrap around the contents of its children.

Comment: where do i need to insert that?

Comment: Insert it into a CSS file and link that CSS file onto the html page that the jQuery script is located in. Here is an example: [http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp)